# ArcGIS Pro 3.0: Changing coordinate system in dynamic text to show XY coordinates not dms, dd etc

Tags: coordinate-system, arcgis-pro, dynamic-text, map-series

I am producing a map series and trying to edit dynamic text in ArcGIS Pro 3.0 to show XY coordinates rather than the default degrees minutes seconds or decimal degrees.

[image: screengrab of dynamic text editing box]

I am in the UK and would like to show X Y coordinates for the centre of the map in a box rather than dms or dd as my map is projected to OSGB. I've looked at the dynamic text guidance for map frame coordinates but the only options are dms or dd (or variations thereof). Despite much googling and trying out a few things in the units bit of the syntax (British_National_Grid, BNG, XY) I can't find out if it's possible to change this to show X: 123456 Y: 123456 so it looks like this (ignore the OSGB ref bit, I know how to add that):

[image: image of OSGB xy coordinates]

Can anyone help? If all else fails I'll add it in the PDF but there must be a way of doing this and I am determined to make it work! Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The closest I was able to do is by using :

```
OSBG reference (map centre)
X : <dyn type="mapFrame" name="Map 1" property="center.x" units="m" decimalPlaces="0"/>
Y : <dyn type="mapFrame" name="Map 1" property="center.y" units="m" decimalPlaces="0"/>
```

Witch result in

[image]

As you can see using `units="m"` is effective to display the actual projected coordinate (in my exemple I use a projected CRS that is not OSBG so the coordinate may seem wrong to you) and it's easy to separate the x and y component using `property="center.x"` and `property="center.y"` the problem is the E and N suffix still appearing after the coordinate and before the unit…

Answer (score 0):

- Get rid of the "units" tag, to get rid of the "m" in the displayed text
- Add the "showDirections" tag, do disable the "E" and "N" in the displayed text

Like this:

```
OSBG reference (map centre)
X : <dyn type="mapFrame" name="Map Frame" property="center.x" decimalPlaces="0" showDirections="False"/>
Y : <dyn type="mapFrame" name="Map Frame" property="center.y" decimalPlaces="0" showDirections="False"/>
```

This gets you that:

[image: screenshot1 coordinate formatting]

If you also want to add thousands-separator for better readability, add the following tag: separator="True":

```
OSBG reference (map centre)
X : <dyn type="mapFrame" name="Map Frame" property="center.x" decimalPlaces="0" showDirections="False" separator="True"/>
Y : <dyn type="mapFrame" name="Map Frame" property="center.y" decimalPlaces="0" showDirections="False" separator="True"/>
```

results in this:

[image: screenshot2 coordinate formatting]